# ORACLE 10g : To_date() Not a valid month

Tags: oracle, to-date

So I have this little script :

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  val DATE;
BEGIN
  val := TO_DATE('27-Jan-2001','DD-Mon-YYYY');
  dbms_output.put_line(val);
END;
```

The mask match with the date I'm inputing but it displays

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

every time...

Thanks

Comment: copy/paste'd your script, works fine for me

Comment: Try `val := TO_DATE('27-JAN-2001','DD-MON-YYYY');` - see if it works. Also, checkout the NLS parameters of the database, by issuing `show parameter nls`. Paste the result here.

Comment: My nls_date_format is DD/MM/RR   
Same error with val := TO_DATE('27-JAN-2001','DD-MON-YYYY')

Comment: What do you get by `select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE';` - I assume it is neither "american" nor "english".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely your current session `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` is set to a value where January is not abbreviated as "Jan".

Try this:

```
DECLARE
  val DATE;
BEGIN
  val := TO_DATE('27-Jan-2001','DD-Mon-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american');
  dbms_output.put_line(val);
END;
```

Or execute

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'american';
```

before you run your PL/SQL block.

Comment: Thanks it worked with the  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american' parameter!