# To_char and To_date

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, to-date, to-char

I'm struggling with one report contain a varchar2 column as a date in MON-YY format

what I wanna do is convert the value of that column into date so I can do some process on it such as filtering with > or < or even between and set two dates

My column name:  BAL.PERIOD_NAME
below is the condition cussing error ORA-01843: not a valid month

```
AND TO_DATE(BAL.PERIOD_NAME,'MON-YY')  > TO_DATE('FEB-18','MON-YY')
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You probably don't have a legit `MON` (month abbreviation) in your `BAL.PERIOD_NAME` for one of your records and so it is unable to convert to date. Perhaps it has something to do with your [NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939248/oracle-10g-to-date-not-a-valid-month) or you just have bad data. Also `TO_DATE('FEB-18', 'MON-YY')` is an expensive way to say `DATE '2018-02-01'`

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are using the correct format mask for the date you are converting.

Works:

```
select  TO_DATE('feb-18','MON-YY') from dual
```

Throws "not a valid month" error:

```
select  TO_DATE('02-18','MON-YY') from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE to check you table for invalif month names.

```
WITH cte(month)
AS
(
SELECT 1 month
       FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT month + 1 month
       FROM cte
       WHERE month + 1 <= 12
)
SELECT *
       FROM bal
       WHERE substr(period_name, 1, 3) NOT IN (SELECT to_char(to_date(month, 'MM'), 'MON')
                                                      FROM cte);
```

Answer (score 1):

Storing date values as strings like `'FEB-18'` is really a design flaw. You should consider a migration to `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) data type.

- Did you never heard about the [Year-2000-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)? Well, I assume when **everybody** in IT world was talking about the Y2K problem many present software developers were still kids.
- The string can be malformed in any way.
- Even if the string has correct format you may face problem with language settings.

Anyway, perhaps it is only a language issue. Try this one

```
WHERE TO_DATE(BAL.PERIOD_NAME,'MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') > DATE '2018-02-01'
```

In case you are running Oracle 12.2 or later you can use function [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD):

```
WHERE VALIDATE_CONVERSION(BAL.PERIOD_NAME, 'MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') = 1
```

If you don't have Oracle 12.2 yet then write your own function, for example like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CONVERT_TO_DATE(str in VARCAHR2) RETURN DATE IS
BEGIN
   RETURN TO_DATE(str, 'MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN NULL;  
END CONVERT_TO_DATE;
```